# Boolean algebra expression simplification in conjuction normal form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Is there a way to simplify this expression:
 
*(!a || !c || b) && (!a || b) && (a) && (!a || !b || c) && (!b || !d || a) && (d || !c || !b) && (!d || e)*

This [calculator](http://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator) returned me expression: 
*(a) && (b) && (c) && (d) && (e)*

I woud like to ask you, if anybody know how to simplify it with steps.

Thank you :)

Have nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main sources of simplification here are:

- $(\lnot x\lor  y) \land x=(\lnot x\land x)\lor (y\land x)=0\lor(x\land y)=x\land y$
- $(\lnot x\lor\lnot y\lor z) \land x\land y=x\land(\lnot y\lor z)\land y=x\land y\land z$

And also commutativity and associativity of $\lor$ and $\land$.

Let's split your expression into pieces $A\land B\land C\land D\land E\land F\land G$

$\begin{array}{l}
A=(\lnot a\lor\lnot c\lor b)\\
B=(\lnot a\lor b)\\
C=a\\
D=(\lnot a\lor\lnot b\lor c)\\
E=(\lnot b\lor\lnot d\lor a)\\
F=(\lnot b\lor\lnot c\lor d)\\
G=(\lnot d\lor e)\\
\end{array}$

So now this is a chain reaction

$B\land C=a\land b\\
B\land C\land D=a\land b\land c\\
B\land C\land D\land A=a\land b\land c\\
B\land C\land D\land A\land F=a\land b\land c\land d\\
B\land C\land D\land A\land F\land E=a\land b\land c\land d\\
B\land C\land D\land A\land F\land E\land G=a\land b\land c\land d\land e\\
$